# How is this potentiometer connected? Is pin 2 not connected? It makes no sense

Tags: potentiometer

How is this potentiometer connected? Is pin 2 not connected? It makes no sense...
The resistance between pin 1 and 3 is always the same, so why is pin 2 not connected?

[image: LM324-based VU meter schematic]

(Image source: [Electronics Area - 8 LED VU meter circuit using LM324 IC](https://electronicsarea.com/8-led-vu-meter-made-ic-lm324/))

I connected pin 3 to 12 V, pin 2 to the rest of the circuit, and left pin 1 not connected. It works fine, but I'm wondering if I just don't understand this drawing?
Thanks.

Comment: if you are talking about the symbol labeled P1 ... that is a symbol for `variable resistor` .... that diagram does not show any pin numbering ... how would you know which pin is Pin 2?

Comment: Easy.  Potentiometer pin numbering was standardized before I got into electronics in the 1960's.  Pin 1 is the counter-clockwise rotation end (CCW), pin 2 is the wiper, and pin 3 is the clockwise rotation end (CW).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's connected as a rheostat. So you would either connect between the wiper and one end, or (better) tie the wiper to one end.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ficHQS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A small detail but it makes the design better- it's good to pick the end you use so that the direction of the pot rotation makes the circuit behave in an expected way.

In this case, you might want to have the pot at maximum resistance when turned fully clockwise since that reduces the reference voltages and increases the bar graph display reading.

Answer (score 1):

When you see a schematic signal like that it means to connect to one end of the fixed element and to the wiper.

It's pretty common to connect the wiper to the other end of the fixed element (i.e., using your pin numbering, you'd connect pins 2 & 3 together, and your variable resistance would be between 1 and the 2+3 pair).